# Controlling displaying option in 2 list using jsp and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, bootstrap-4

I'm using coreui.io in one of my project coded with jsp and on a page, I have 2 dropdown list like this:

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="card"> List 1 </label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="arg1">
                         <option >option 1</option>
                           <option>option 2</option>
                     </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Then, I have:

```
<div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="bank"> List 2 </label>
                     <select class="form-control" name="arg2">
                         <option>1. related to selection of option1</option>
                         <option>2. related to selection of option1</option>
                         <option>3. related to selection of option2</option>
                         <option>4. related to selection of option2</option>
                     </select>
             </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

My question is that I want whenever user select option1 in List 1, automatically see only option 1 and 2 in List 2 and whenever select option 2 in List 1, see only option 3 and 4 in List 2. I'm using jsp and bootsrap4(coreui.io)
How Can I do this?
The another question is that when we have too many options, it's really boring to scroll these option to the end, Do we have better feature tho display rather than a dropdown list?
Regards